# How to change NextJS 404 page for API?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm creating an API with `NextJS 12.3.1`.

Example: `/api/v1/modules`

If user loads a unknown page like: `/api/v1/blablabla` or `/api/go`, NextJs return a **404 HTML** page as answer.

How to change the 404 page to a json like `{ "error": "Resource not found" }` when trying to load unknown endpoints inside `api` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new route to access the JSON, just create a wildcard for all other pages. Call the API by using the wildcard and addressing it to that route.

```
page/api/[[...404]].js
```

If you have an API endpoint that doesn't matches an existing page, this page will show if the API route doesn't exist.